# How to make this code on each loop, move the ranges it copies 2 columns to the right

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code if it finds a value is True, it copies 3 ranges to 1 of 5 worksheets and prints. It then loops again and repeats till the end, this works exactly how I want it to. So 1 page is printed each time it finds a True value.

What I am trying to do here is modify the if that value is False.

Each loop I need it to copy the same 3 ranges to 1 of 5 different worksheets. Here thou instead of printing on each loop, I need it to copy the next 3 ranges on the same sheet but 2 columns to the right. I have this worksheet setup to fit 5 of these copied ranges per page, if there are more it moves to next page and repeats. There are 14 loops per row and at completion of a row it then prints, before it moves to next 5.

I have 5 rows with 14 columns, this is where either True, False or 1 are located. This is the formula that is in those 70 cells `=IF(AND(SUMPRODUCT(--ISBLANK(Nuna1))<>ROWS(Nuna1)),D9<>2,1)`
The cells in the 5 rows all have a named range and each row has a different name
Nuna1 through 14
Verm1 through 14
Mitch1 through 14
Black1 through 14
Boxhill1 through 14
Here is the code I am trying to modify to achieve this

```
Dim shData As Worksheet, shGroup As Worksheet
Dim arrSh As Variant, arrCe As Variant, arrRn As Variant, arrCl As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, lr As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
arrSh = Array("Nunawading Bus", "Vermont Bus", "Mitcham Bus", "Blackburn Bus", "Box Hill Bus")     'Names of the 5 destinations Sheets
arrCe = Array(23, 33, 43, 58, 78) 'Rows where arrRn ranges are located,
arrRn = Array("Nuna", "Verm", "Mitch", "Black", "Boxhill") 'The ranges that get copied and each have a number like Nuna1 through to Last Nuna14
arrNm = Array("Name")
arrCo = Array("Code")
arrCl = Array("Clear7", "Clear8", "Clear9", "Clear10", "Clear11") 'This clears the Destinations sheets after Printing is complete


Set shData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Week Commencing")
 For i = 0 To UBound(arrSh)
  Set shGroup = Sheets(arrSh(i))
  k = 1
  For j = Columns("D").Column To Columns("Q").Column
   If shData.Cells(arrCe(i), j) = False Then
      shData.Range(arrRn(i) & k).Copy
      lr = 5
       shGroup.Range("B7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
      shData.Range(arrNm(0) & k).Copy
        
       shGroup.Range("C4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        
      shData.Range(arrCo(0) & k).Copy
        
      shGroup.Range("C5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
   'MsgBox Printed
   shGroup.PrintPreview
  
   End If
   k = k + 1
 Next j
Next i

For i = 0 To UBound(arrSh)
Set shGroup = Sheets(arrSh(i))
 shGroup.Range(arrCl(i)).ClearContents
  Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Do a little googling for more info but, you can set a destination for your data using `Range.Offset`. `Offset` allows you to reference adjacent cells in any direction. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think it would have to go in some sort of a loop as each time the loop runs it would need to move it say 2 columns to the right.

Comment: Yeah a [For...Next loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement) should help with that. Use your counter reference in your column criteria of the offset property. Also make use of the `step` part of the loop which allows you to dictate how much each loop step will increment/decrement. (e.g. `step 2` will increase the counter by 2 each iteration of your loop)

Comment: I have tried so many ways to try to get this to work, but I am completely lost and confused. Any further help would be great